# Installing MariaDB on top of Ubuntu via Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

So I have a problem. I am using Docker CE on Windows 10 and I am trying to install MariaDB on top of Ubuntu using Dockerfile.

This is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

This is how it looks like, then I would go into the container via interactive mode to run command such as "mysql -u root" but it would say

> "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through
> socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such  file or directory")"

Also, when building the image via Dockerfile, there would be these sentences that might be an error as well.

> debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
>
> debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
>
> invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
>
> invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.

Anyone has any idea how can I get pass all these issues? Rather, I would want to be able to run the command "mysql -u root" and some other commands via Dockerfile eventually. Right now I am manually doing it via interactive mode for docker run to see the error that it returns.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you starting the database?  What's your image's `CMD` when a container runs?  It might be easier to use the [Docker Hub `mariadb` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) and its `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` initialization mechanism.

Comment: `mysql -u root`
`use mysql`
`update user set plugin='' where User='root';`
`flush privileges;`
`exit`

Those are the commands that I want to run after installing MariaDB, it works when I have Ubuntu running on a rpi but when I try to replicate it using Dockerfile, it does not work...

Comment: The same container will also be installed with phpmyadmin as well...